# Как выставить разные border-img на стороны блока left / right / top / bottom?

Tags: html, css

Как выставить разные border-img на стороны блока left / right / top / bottom?
Гугление привело к выставлению картинки одной на все стороны, однако у меня идут разные img. И к тому же, `border-radius` почему то перестает работать на `border-img`... а надо что бы бордер был картинкой, и окрегленные края.

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` на самом деле прекрасно работает, просто вы не можете этого видеть. Рамка скруглена, но картинки как бы "вылазят" за ее пределы.

Я вижу 2 варианта обхода данного поведения.

1. Использовать картинки с заранее нарисованным скруглением
2. Заключить блок с рамкой в еще один блок, к которому уже применить в свою очередь `border-radius`.

Что касается отдельных картинок, приведу выдержку [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542961/5899212):

> It is not actually possible to do this with separate image files, but you can slice a single image on the left and right. See the border-image page on MDN which shows some good examples or CSS Tricks for a comprehensive summary of how the other slicing options work.

Там же, кстати, и содержатся примерные пути обхода вашей ситуации, а именно - ссылки на примеры того, как можно "нарезать" картинку, чтобы она использовать ее как рамку для каждой стороны отдельно.

---

Дополнительно: если вам известна заранее высота блока, то вы можете поместить его наверх другого блока, где фоном является ваша картинка (одна) со всеми рамками. Вот такой вот костыль.